# Unable to send email via WP-SMTP Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, contact-form-7

I have contact form 7 in my website and I am using WP-SMTP plugin to send form data to my gmail account.

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the plugin.
[image]

and in Functions.php I have added the following code.

```
/*Send email*/
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_init' );
function my_phpmailer_init( PHPMailer $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.net';
    $phpmailer->Port = 465; // could be different
    $phpmailer->Username = 'alisda.residency@gmail.com'; // if required
    $phpmailer->Password = *******; // if required
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // if required
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // enable if required, 'tls' is another possible value
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();
}
```

but I receive the following error

```
Test Message Sent
The result was:
bool(false)
The full debugging output is shown below:
object(PHPMailer)#1551 (76) {
   ["Version"]=>
   string(6) "5.2.22"
   ["Priority"]=>
   NULL
   ["CharSet"]=>
string(5) "UTF-8"
["ContentType"]=>
string(10) "text/plain"
["Encoding"]=>
string(4) "7bit"
["ErrorInfo"]=>
string(82) "SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"
["From"]=>
string(26) "alisda.residency@gmail.com"
["FromName"]=>
string(9) "My Alisda"
["Sender"]=>
string(0) ""
["ReturnPath"]=>
string(0) ""
["Subject"]=>
string(50) "WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to shivanand3939@gmail.com"
["Body"]=>
string(68) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin."
["AltBody"]=>
string(0) ""
["Ical"]=>
string(0) ""
["MIMEBody":protected]=>
string(69) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin.
"
["MIMEHeader":protected]=>
string(369) "Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 05:13:00 +0000
To: shivanand3939@gmail.com
From: My Alisda 
Subject: WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to shivanand3939@gmail.com
Message-ID: 
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

"
["mailHeader":protected]=>
string(0) ""
["WordWrap"]=>
int(0)
["Mailer"]=>
string(4) "smtp"
["Sendmail"]=>
string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
["UseSendmailOptions"]=>
bool(true)
["PluginDir"]=>
string(0) ""
["ConfirmReadingTo"]=>
string(0) ""
["Hostname"]=>
string(0) ""
["MessageID"]=>
string(0) ""
["MessageDate"]=>
string(31) "Fri, 27 Jan 2017 05:13:00 +0000"
["Host"]=>
string(14) "smtp.gmail.net"
["Port"]=>
int(465)
["Helo"]=>
string(0) ""
["SMTPSecure"]=>
string(3) "ssl"
["SMTPAutoTLS"]=>
bool(true)
["SMTPAuth"]=>
bool(true)
["SMTPOptions"]=>
array(0) {
}
["Username"]=>
string(26) "alisda.residency@gmail.com"
["Password"]=>
**********
["AuthType"]=>
string(0) ""
["Realm"]=>
string(0) ""
["Workstation"]=>
string(0) ""
["Timeout"]=>
int(300)
["SMTPDebug"]=>
bool(true)
["Debugoutput"]=>
string(4) "echo"
["SMTPKeepAlive"]=>
bool(false)
["SingleTo"]=>
bool(false)
["SingleToArray"]=>
array(0) {
}
["do_verp"]=>
bool(false)
["AllowEmpty"]=>
bool(false)
["LE"]=>
string(1) "
"
["DKIM_selector"]=>
string(0) ""
["DKIM_identity"]=>
string(0) ""
["DKIM_passphrase"]=>
string(0) ""
["DKIM_domain"]=>
string(0) ""
["DKIM_private"]=>
string(0) ""
["DKIM_private_string"]=>
string(0) ""
["action_function"]=>
string(0) ""
["XMailer"]=>
string(0) ""
["smtp":protected]=>
object(SMTP)#1552 (14) {
  ["Version"]=>
  string(6) "5.2.22"
  ["SMTP_PORT"]=>
  int(25)
  ["CRLF"]=>
  string(2) "
"
  ["do_debug"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["Debugoutput"]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  ["do_verp"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["Timeout"]=>
  int(300)
  ["Timelimit"]=>
  int(300)
  ["smtp_transaction_id_patterns":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    ["exim"]=>
    string(21) "/[0-9]{3} OK id=(.*)/"
    ["sendmail"]=>
    string(29) "/[0-9]{3} 2.0.0 (.*) Message/"
    ["postfix"]=>
    string(35) "/[0-9]{3} 2.0.0 Ok: queued as (.*)/"
  }
  ["smtp_conn":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["error":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["error"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["detail"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["smtp_code"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["smtp_code_ex"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["helo_rply":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["server_caps":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["last_reply":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
}
["to":protected]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "shivanand3939@gmail.com"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
["cc":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["bcc":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["ReplyTo":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["all_recipients":protected]=>
array(1) {
  ["shivanand3939@gmail.com"]=>
  bool(true)
}
["RecipientsQueue":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["ReplyToQueue":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["attachment":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["CustomHeader":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["lastMessageID":protected]=>
string(58) ""
["message_type":protected]=>
string(5) "plain"
["boundary":protected]=>
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(35) "b1_ab0450b0fa3fa25b2fadbefee8bd80f6"
  [2]=>
  string(35) "b2_ab0450b0fa3fa25b2fadbefee8bd80f6"
  [3]=>
  string(35) "b3_ab0450b0fa3fa25b2fadbefee8bd80f6"
}
["language":protected]=>
array(19) {
  ["authenticate"]=>
  string(35) "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate."
  ["connect_host"]=>
  string(43) "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."
  ["data_not_accepted"]=>
  string(30) "SMTP Error: data not accepted."
  ["empty_message"]=>
  string(18) "Message body empty"
  ["encoding"]=>
  string(18) "Unknown encoding: "
  ["execute"]=>
  string(19) "Could not execute: "
  ["file_access"]=>
  string(23) "Could not access file: "
  ["file_open"]=>
  string(33) "File Error: Could not open file: "
  ["from_failed"]=>
  string(35) "The following From address failed: "
  ["instantiate"]=>
  string(36) "Could not instantiate mail function."
  ["invalid_address"]=>
  string(17) "Invalid address: "
  ["mailer_not_supported"]=>
  string(25) " mailer is not supported."
  ["provide_address"]=>
  string(54) "You must provide at least one recipient email address."
  ["recipients_failed"]=>
  string(45) "SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: "
  ["signing"]=>
  string(15) "Signing Error: "
  ["smtp_connect_failed"]=>
  string(22) "SMTP connect() failed."
  ["smtp_error"]=>
  string(19) "SMTP server error: "
  ["variable_set"]=>
  string(30) "Cannot set or reset variable: "
  ["extension_missing"]=>
  string(19) "Extension missing: "
}
["error_count":protected]=>
int(2)
["sign_cert_file":protected]=>
string(0) ""
["sign_key_file":protected]=>
string(0) ""
["sign_extracerts_file":protected]=>
string(0) ""
["sign_key_pass":protected]=>
string(0) ""
["exceptions":protected]=>
bool(true)
["uniqueid":protected]=>
string(32) "ab0450b0fa3fa25b2fadbefee8bd80f6"
}
The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
2017-01-27 05:13:00 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.net:465, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2017-01-27 05:13:00 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
2017-01-27 05:13:00 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.net:465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
2017-01-27 05:13:00 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
2017-01-27 05:13:00 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I have also tried WP Gmail SMTP Plugin but again there is an error while sending emails.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: is on your server smtp installed?

Comment: Did you try replacing `smtp.gmail.net` with `smtp.gmail.com`?

Comment: @NehalJWani Yes I tried changing but it did not work

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap could you please tellif there is a SMTP plugin that I should install

Answer (score 0):

kindly check following setting in you SMTP setting page in admin:

```
- Mailer: Send all WordPress emails via SMTP.
- Encryption: Use SSL encryption.
- Authentication: Yes: Use SMTP authentication.
```

Then try test email.

Hope it will works for your code.

Comment: should I install a SMTP plugin, if yes, will any SMTP plugin work?

Comment: upload this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/. it is very useful and handy plugin and set settings as i mentioned in answer.

Comment: I used the same plugin and tried with the settings you mentioned, I still get the same error

Comment: try this plugin to check emails are enable in your server or not? or in your custom plugin check default PHP mail function running or not?https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-email/ so we can check email are enabled or not.